# Block form submit if no one checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I need help because confused how to block form submit if no one checkbox checked.

```js
var $form = $('#send-invite-form');
var $checkbox = $('input[class^="invitation-friends"]');

$form.on('submit', function(e) {
  $.each($checkbox, function(index, value) {
    if (!$(value).is(':checked')) {
      alert('Opps! You not select friends.');
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="send-invite-form">
  <input type="checkbox" class="invitation-friends" value="875" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="invitation-friends" value="394" />
  <button type="submit">Send</submit>
    </form>
```

The code check every checkbox. I don't want it. I want if one checkbox checked, the form can submit. If no one checked, bail submit.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to do this that is much simpler than what you are doing. There's no need to loop. Just used the `:checked` pseudo-class selector to get a set of nodes that are checked and check the `.length` of the resulting set of nodes. If the `.length` is `0`, no checkboxes have been checked.

```js
$( '#send-invite-form' ).on('submit', function(e) {
   if($( 'input[class^="invitation-friends"]:checked' ).length === 0) {
      alert( 'Oops! You not select friends.' );
      e.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="send-invite-form">
     <input type="checkbox" class="invitation-friends" value="875" />
     <input type="checkbox" class="invitation-friends" value="394" />

     <button type="submit">Send</submit>
</form>
```

Comment: Nice! but why if i replace with `var $checkbox = $( 'input[class^="invitation-friends"]:checked' )` , so look like `if($checkbox.length === 0) {` the code not working nice.

Comment: @Opsional You could do that, but you'd have to set up the variable inside of the `submit` event handler so that you get the most up to date set of elements at the moment the form is submitted. And, since you are only using that set once, setting up the variable is a waste, so that's why my code doesn't do it.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem comes from this line :

```
if ( !$(value).is(':checked')) {
```

Should be :

```
if ( !$(this).is(':checked')) {
```

Since `value` contains the value of the selected checkbox not the object, so `$(value)` will not work.

Then if you want to submit with at least one checkbox you could check the length of checked input's like :

```
if( $('input.invitation-friends:checked').length == 0 )
{
    return false; 
}
```

Hope this helps.

```js
var $form = $('#send-invite-form');
var $checkbox = $('input[class^="invitation-friends"]');

$form.on('submit', function(e) {
  if( $('input.invitation-friends:checked').length == 0 )
  {
    return false; 
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="send-invite-form">
  <input type="checkbox" class="invitation-friends" value="875" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="invitation-friends" value="394" />

  <button type="submit">Send</submit>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this, no need to explain i think:

```
var found = false;
$.each( $checkbox, function(index, value) {
    if( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
        found = true;
    }
});
if(!found){
    alert( 'Opps! You not select friends.' );
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since submit button is controlling form submit, I am controlling its enable/disable status based on checkbox click

```js
window.onload = checkBoxEventAndOnSubmitFunctionality();

  function checkBoxEventAndOnSubmitFunctionality() {
    let checkBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName('invitation-friends');
    let checkBoxChecked = 0;
    
    for(i=0;i<checkBoxes.length;i++) {
       checkBoxes[i].onclick = function(e) {
          if(e.path[0].checked) checkBoxChecked += 1;
          else checkBoxChecked -= 1;
       }
    }
    document.getElementById("send-invite-form").onsubmit = function(e) {
      if(checkBoxChecked !=0) {
        alert("can submit");
         document.getElementById("send-invite-form").submit();
      }
      else {
        alert("can NOT submit");
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
<form id="send-invite-form" onsubmit="checkForCheckBoxes" method="POST">
     <input type="checkbox" class="invitation-friends" value="875" />
     <input type="checkbox" class="invitation-friends" value="394" />

     <button type="submit" id="submitButton">Send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This is not actually a good idea from a UI perspective since it is possible to submit a form (under certain circumstances) by pressing ENTER. Your code doesn't actually prevent the form from being submitted in all cases. The best way to control form submitting is with the `submit` event of the form.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thank your for the insight; will tweak the approach , first thing tomorrow

Comment: @ScottMarcus I have tweaked the code to suit your insight; will this do?

Comment: It's a step in the right direction, but there is no need to loop through the checkboxes and count how many are checked. Just use: `if($( 'input[class^="invitation-friends"]:checked' ).length === 0) {` to know if there are any checked or not. Also, in the submit event handler, you don't need to submit the form via code (submit has already been initiated by the user). All you need to do is potentially stop it. Lastly, it's better to use `.addEventListener()` to register event callbacks than to use `onclick` or `onsubmit` properties.